# android: java.io.FileNotFoundException (Too many open files) at decodeFile method

Tags: android, bitmap, filenotfoundexception

i am doing a liveview streaming of image.

i realised that after running my program for around few minutes, the application will close by itself with the following window error: java.io.FileNotFoundException (Too many open files)

tracing the logcat output, the error happen at around this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
```

i see that there a few similar question but it do not provide much solution.

since the eorror is i am opening too much files because of this decodeFile method, is there any way for me to close this file reference?

thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is open the file yourself, pass the inputstream to the decodeStream method of BitmapFactory, then close the file yourself.

Comment: hi, how do i access the decodestream method of bitmap factory. the "file" variable that i putting into the decodefile right now is in fact a string type.

Comment: It'd be something like this: `FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(<path>); Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); is.close();`

Comment: Well, are you completely sure you don't open any other files and you close the file like I said?

Comment: hi, i tried to close all file stream. i now having the "Could not create 2367488-byte ashmem mark stack. dvmHeapBeginMarkStep failed; aborting" any idea why is this so?